Does SQLAlchemy automatically closes a connection in a with statement?
I’m refactoring some legacy code and converting the use of pyodbc to SQLAlchemy. Every time a connection to the database is created (with pyodbc) in this code, it is closed after use. This sounds right and it is right, but can’t I just eliminate this using a with statement? (At least in SQLAlchemy)
I'm going to be using this:
with engine.connect() as connection:
    try:
        count= pd.read_sql(
            sql = text("SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM [table]"),
            con = connection
        ).loc[0, ("Count")]
    
    except KeyError:
        quantidade_ordens = 0

Are there any issues of not using connection.close()?

Technically, SQLAlchemy has a connection pool, so the connection isn't closed immediately, but that's essentially correct.
